# dnnEditState showing on users without edit rights

Tags: .net, css, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN site and have several users at subscriber level security role.  My issue is that I have some things set to show or hide based on the id dnnEditState that is applied for users with roles for editing the website.  Some users at the subscriber level security role are given this id and some are not.  None should get the id.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by verifying that the users are members of Multiple roles, and you don't have any Edit permissions defined at the module or page level, for roles that you don't intend to have permissions to Edit.

You will want to check the Page and Module permissions for every page that has the issue you describe.